# Meteor accounts-facebook Valid OAuth redirect URIs issue Facebook March update

Tags: facebook, meteor, oauth

I'm using meter version 1.3.2.4

Facebook has announced that Valid OAuth redirect URIs must be included for apps using their service starting in March.

> "In March, we're making a security update to your app settings that will invalidate calls from URIs not listed in the Valid OAuth redirect URIs field below.This update comes in response to malicious activity we saw on our platform, and we want to protect your app or website by requiring a new strict mode for redirect URIs."

I am adding what is the correct OAuth redirect URI for my application `http://myapp.com/_oauth/facebook?close`

After adding this redirect URI though I'm getting an error when trying to login:

`Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again.`

Any ideas here?

Comment: Do you have any more logs you can share?

Comment: That doesn’t sounds like a Facebook error message, but something output by your app itself. So you will need to do some debugging, and see what the API actually responds with.

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer I am getting no error logs in my application, these error messages are being shown in the Facebook oauth popup. I would've posted the screenshots but am unable (not enough rep)